Create a Pyspark standalone executable
I'm trying to bundle my pyspark project into a standalone executable so my client can execute it on their computer without the need to install Python, Spark or Java.
At the moment I'm trying this with PyInstaller and this is the process:

I have a copy of Pyspark at the root of the project

This is my .spec file:


a = Analysis(
    ['main.py'],
    pathex=[],
    binaries=[],
    datas=[('.env', '.'), ('pyspark/', 'pyspark')],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries,
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='main',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)


I have this at the start of the script:

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
pyspark_path = os.path.join(current_dir, "pyspark")
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = pyspark_path
os.environ["PYSPARK_PYTHON"] = sys.executable
os.environ["PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON"] = sys.executable


I just run pyinstaller main.spec

When I try to run the executable on a computer without anything installed it gives me the following error:
 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 7.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 7)/ 8]
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Python worker failed to connect back.

Both computers are running Windows.
Is what I'm trying to achieve here possible? If so what am I doing wrong?
